# C# Excel Chart Change color

Tags: excel, colors, charts

I am trying to change the line color of the chart series to None. I tried setting the color and the marker property but the program errors out.

My code:

```
 Excel.ChartObjects _ChartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(oSheet1.ChartObjects(Missing.Value));
            Excel.ChartObject _ChartObject = _ChartObjects.Add(170, 0, 400, 300);
            Excel.Chart _Chart = _ChartObject.Chart;
            Excel.Range oRng1;
            oRng1 = oSheet1.get_Range("A1","E55");            
            _Chart.SetSourceData(oRng1, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
            _Chart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
            oWB.ShowPivotChartActiveFields = true;
            //_Chart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12;
            _Chart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementDataTableWithLegendKeys);
            _Chart.DataTable.Font.Size = 6;
            oWB.ShowPivotChartActiveFields = false;
            _Chart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated);
            _Chart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementLegendNone);
            //_Chart.Legend.Delete();
            _Chart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleNone);
            _Chart.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet, "Tax Weekly Term-Chart");
           Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)_Chart.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing);

            Excel.Series series = (Excel.Series)seriesCollection.Item(4);
```

Need code to set the color of the series to None.Any suggestions would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This code can set the colours of the slices of all the pie charts in my spreadsheet based on each slice's legend's label:

```
Sub SetPieChartColours()

    ' Iterates through all pie charts in the dashboard and apply colours to the appropriate legends

    ' Colour indices:
    ' Passed (Green)             10
    ' Not Completed (Yellow)     19
    ' No run (Blue)              37
    ' Failed (Maroon)            18
    ' Failed Issue (Pink)        24
    ' Failed Defect (Red)        3

    Dim savePtLabel As String
    Dim ThisPt As String

    Dim NumPoints As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Dim pie As ChartObject
    For Each pie In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

         ' Check that the current chart object is a pie chart
         If pie.Chart.ChartType = xlPie Then

            NumPoints = pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
            For x = 1 To NumPoints

                ' Save the label currently attached to the current slice
                If pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).HasDataLabel = True Then
                    savePtLabel = pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel.Text
                Else
                    savePtLabel = ""
                End If

                ' Assign a new data label of just the point name
                pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).ApplyDataLabels Type:= _
                   xlDataLabelsShowLabel, AutoText:=True
                ThisPt = pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel.Text

                ' Based on the label of this slice, set the color
                Select Case ThisPt
                    Case "Failed-Defect"
                        pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Case "Failed-Issue"
                        pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                    Case "Failed"
                        pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 18
                    Case "No Run"
                        pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                    Case "Not Completed"
                        pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 18
                    Case "Passed"
                        pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                    Case Else
                        ' Aroo! The label of the current slice doesn't match any expected labels
                        pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
                End Select

                ' Return the label to it's original state
                pie.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowNone, AutoText:=True

            Next x
         End If
     Next

End Sub
```

And this code can set barchart colours:

```
Sub SetBarChartColours()

    Dim savePtLabel As String
    Dim ThisPt As String

    Dim NumPoints As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Dim bar As ChartObject

    For Each bar In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
       If bar.Chart.Name = "Dashboard Chart 5" Then
            NumPoints = bar.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
            For x = 1 To NumPoints
                MsgBox bar.Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(x).LegendKey.Interior.ColorIndex


            Next x
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Maybe could help you!